# Resubmission on load asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, form-submit, redirect

I am working on a **C# project** using **asp framework  4.5** and I am having this problem :

**I want a way to avoid a resubmission of the form on page refresh (without self redirect):**

When refreshing the page, the button does trigger itself, I need to avoid the second submission without page redirection .
I am trying to upload a file, on the first try every thing is Working fine, but, when I hit `f5` to refresh the page, the form will be resubmitted.

Comment: I would ask why you are hitting F5?

Comment: Why not posting in the background using javascript and then redirecting to the regular `GET` page?

Comment: I am hitting F5 for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
    public bool IsPageRefresh = false;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
        {
              ViewState["postids"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Session["postid"] = ViewState["postids"].ToString();

       }
        else
        {
            if (ViewState["postids"].ToString() != Session["postid"].ToString())
            {
                IsPageRefresh = true;
            }
            Session["postid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            ViewState["postids"] = Session["postid"].ToString();
        }

 }
```

just check below condition on button click

```
 if (!IsPageRefresh)
     {
       // write you post code
      }
```

try this it's working perfect for me .